# Eclipse & old awt application testing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

I have an old AWT/swing application.  It was originally built on NetBeans, but I was told that 'stuff' was taken out.  We now use Eclipse.  I've gotten the application to compile and it runs fine with a command line .bat file.

Does anyone know how I can run this though eclipse?  It seems to me I'm missing a jar file or something somewhere.

I'm running eclipse Helios SR1 with JDK 1.6.0_23.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Hashtable Enumerator
    at java.util.Hashtable$EmptyEnumerator.nextElement(Hashtable.java:1084)
    at com.protobase.dt.graphics.DevTransUI.initComponents(DevTransUI.java:1462)
    at com.protobase.dt.graphics.DevTransUI.<init>(DevTransUI.java:313)
    at com.protobase.dt.graphics.DevTransUI$42.run(DevTransUI.java:6667)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the application have configuration files that define its user interface?

It looks like that the application has started and submitted a UI initialisation action to the AWT event queue. This has created a new instance of the DevTransUI class. The class constructor is running and, I infer from the method name, is trying to create the user interface.

The presence of the EmptyEnumerator reveals that the Hashtable the DevTransUI is working with is completely empty. As we know it works when executed from a .bat file whatever mechanism by which this Hashtable is normally populated has failed - hence my question about whether it has configuration files.

Fixing this may be just a matter of setting the Working Directory of the launch configuration - you can find this on the Arguments tab.

Comment: You were right, thank you, it needed a properties file.  Thanks so much!